# Light Not showing on object

Tags: javascript, three.js

so Ive been messing with [this](http://coryg89.github.io/technical/2013/06/01/photorealistic-3d-moon-demo-in-webgl-and-javascript/), and Ive finally gotten everything to kind of work for me. I'm a beginner at any type of javascript so I don't know if this is a simple fix. Basically I cant get the light to show up on the moon like how it does in the [original](http://coryg89.github.io/MoonDemo).

Well here is what I have thus far.

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="mainCode">

var container, 
    renderer, 
    scene, 
    camera, 
    mesh,
    light = {
       speed: 0.1,
       distance: 1000,
       position: new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
       orbit: function (center, time) {
            this.position.x =
                (center.x + this.distance) * Math.sin(time * -this.speed);

            this.position.z =
                (center.z + this.distance) * Math.cos(time * this.speed);
        }
    },
    clock,
    controls;


        init();

        function init() {

        // grab the container from the DOM
        container = document.getElementById( "container" );


        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        var fov = 35,
        aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
        near = 1,
        far = 65536;

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, preserveDrawingBuffer: true});   
        renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
        camera.position.set(0, 0, 800);

        scene.add(camera);

        controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
        controls.rotateSpeed = 0.5;
        controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.5;

        clock = new THREE.Clock();

        var radius = 100;
        var xSegments = 50;
        var ySegments = 50;
        var geo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, xSegments, ySegments);

        var mat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
            uniforms: {
                lightPosition: {
                    type: 'v3',
                    value: light.position
                },
                textureMap: {
                    type: 't',
                    value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "img/maps/moon.jpg" )
                },
                normalMap: {
                    type: 't',
                    value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "img/maps/normal.jpg" )
                },
                uvScale: {
                    type: 'v2',
                    value: new THREE.Vector2(1.0, 1.0)

                }


            },
            vertexShader:document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent,
            fragmentShader:document.getElementById('fragmentShader').textContent

        });

          mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);     
          mesh.geometry.computeTangents();
          mesh.position.set(0, 0, 0);
          mesh.rotation.set(0, 180, 0);
          scene.add(mesh);


    }

    function onWindowResize() {
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        light.orbit(mesh.position, clock.getElapsedTime());
        controls.update(camera);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);

    }
    animate();

    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);


</script>
```

Comment: tangent support was removed from three.js r.72. If you want to continue with your existing code, you can try a previous three.js release: http://cdnjs.com/libraries/three.js/. `MeshPhongMaterial` uses "derivative tangents", instead.

Answer (score 0):

You never add any lights to your scene. The moon example uses a custom shader which is more complicated than what you need right now. You need to create a regular Three light and add it to your scene, for example

> http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Lights/PointLight

```
var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xff0000, 1, 100 );
light.position.set( 50, 50, 50 );
scene.add( light );
```

Comment: Will this allow me to only have the light show on the moon and rotate around the moon like in the example?

Comment: I kind of think I know my problem, aside from what you've already pointed out. I dont know if I should post this in a new thread, but the newest revision doesnt seem to support tangents in the same way that this script uses the function, an I thought that didnt matter but I just noticed my shaders rely heavily on them to map the light to the texture as it rotates around my object. So this is what my code looks like, is there any way to update this so it works with the new revision.