# ComputeTangents in rev. 72

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, webgl

In my initial question [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33056747/light-not-showing-on-object) I asked about why my lighting wasn't showing and got an answer based on the info I provided, but I realize i wasn't asking the right question. I kind of think I know my problem now. The newest revision doesn't seem to support tangents in the same way that the original script uses the function, as it seems to automatically delete the .computeTangent command,  and I thought that didn't matter, but I just noticed my shaders rely heavily on this to map the light to the texture as it rotates around my object.

**So this is what my shader scripts look like, is there any way to update this so it works with the newest revision.**

```
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec4 tangent;
uniform vec2 uvScale;
uniform vec3 lightPosition;

varying vec2 vUv;
varying mat3 tbn;
varying vec3 vLightVector;

void main() {
    vUv = uvScale * uv;

    /** Create tangent-binormal-normal matrix used to transform
        coordinates from object space to tangent space */
    vec3 vNormal = normalize(normalMatrix * normal);
    vec3 vTangent = normalize( normalMatrix * tangent.xyz );
    vec3 vBinormal = normalize(cross( vNormal, vTangent ) * tangent.w);
    tbn = mat3(vTangent, vBinormal, vNormal);

    /** Calculate the vertex-to-light vector */
    vec4 lightVector = viewMatrix * vec4(lightPosition, 1.0);
    vec4 modelViewPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    vLightVector = normalize(lightVector.xyz - modelViewPosition.xyz);

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
</script>

<!-- GLSL fragment shader for the moon -->
<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
uniform sampler2D textureMap;
uniform sampler2D normalMap;

varying vec2 vUv;
varying mat3 tbn;
varying vec3 vLightVector;

void main() {
    /** Transform texture coordinate of normal map to a range (-1, 1) */
    vec3 normalCoordinate = texture2D(normalMap, vUv).xyz * 2.0 - 1.0;

    /** Transform the normal vector in the RGB channels to tangent space */
    vec3 normal = normalize(tbn * normalCoordinate.rgb);

    /** Lighting intensity is calculated as dot of normal vector and 
        the vertex-to-light vector */
    float intensity = max(0.07, dot(normal, vLightVector));
    vec4 lighting = vec4(intensity, intensity, intensity, 1.0);

    /** Final color is calculated with the lighting applied */
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(textureMap, vUv) * lighting;
}
```

Comment: Mrdoob says [on github](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/7190)  that **computeTangents() was removed because built-in materials/shaders no longer require tangents.**. So i suppose you should get your own computeTangents (either dispose tangents).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a bit of a beginner. I saw that that was removed, but then how do I get my own computeTangents. Or is there a better way to accomplish what "vertexShader" is doing.

Comment: You are jumping in the deep end for a beginner. As I commented on your other post, try an earlier version of three.js if you want to have any hope of getting your current code working. If you want to use the current version of the library, then use `MeshPhongMaterial` for you moon, instead -- or learn about "derivative tangents" and modify your code.

Comment: Thank you, I did just what you suggested an went back to r71, thank you for the help. I'll check out derivative tangents and try changing my material type. If i change my material type to the MeshPhongMaterial, do I have to modify "vertexShader".

Comment: With all due respect, please do not ask a question before investing the time to answer it yourself.